# Why does preheating the propellant in this fashion improve performance?

Tags: thermodynamics, rocket-science

I'm surprised at the claims by this [resistojet lab](http://www.lr.tudelft.nl/?id=26232). According to their diagram, a resistojet is basically a rocket engine with an ohmic heater in (or around) the last part of the propellant inlet, and this improves performance.

Now, I'm terrible at thermodynamics, but to a first approximation, should the difference between source and sink temperature be as high as possible? As long as the propellant's ready to burn (the igniter's job), what's the use in heating the propellant?

Answer (score 1):

They are *increasing* the temperature difference: the fuel comes in cold, they heat it using two mechanisms: first by dumping energy into it electrically, and then by dumping more into it chemically.

It seems odd to me that there could be plausible scenarios where there is a lot of electrical power available for a rocket that isn't more expensive to generate or store that it would be worth while (either you are carrying batteries or something, or you're running a turbine to make electricity from fuel) but perhaps there can be. And of course there is: if you have solar panels and are driving attitude-control rockets: electrical power is there and you want to minimise fuel usage.

Comment: That explanation assumes that a hotter fuel pre-ignition does more work post-ignition, right?

Comment: @bright-star Well, if you didn't burn the fuel at all you've got what is essentially a steam rocket: burning the fuel just adds more energy to the system.